# Market not working on droid 2 with 2.3.3 after factory reset

Tags: google-play-store, 2.3-gingerbread, updates, motorola-droid-2

I did a factory reset on the phone, to switch to a different email account. Since it's cell service contract expired a while ago, I used [this](http://theunlockr.com/2010/09/20/how-to-bypass-the-activation-screen-on-the-motorola-droid-2/) to bypass activation and get to the home screen, then connected my google account. Before the reset, I had the google play app, and had used it without a problem. Now it's gone, replaced by the Market app.

Whenever I try to open the Market app, it sends me to a web page with the google Play TOS, but no "Accept" button. How do I update to the google Play app?

***EDIT***

Nevermind, my phone seems to have re-installed all of the apps from before it's reset, including google Play.

Comment: Probably you've got them back from your Google Backup (which always takes a while, so one needs some patience :) So your problem is solved? If so, don't hesitate to answer your own question, so people can see there's a solution. Two days after that, you can even accept your own answer.